# pickle, numpy - reshape parameters?

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I'm trying to figure out what the parameters to the `reshape()` function are below.

I didn't find anything about pickle having a `reshape()` method, and `import cPickle as pickle, import numpy as np` were given in the file, so I'm assuming (maybe a bad assumption) that the reshape function is because of numpy. I found the definition of the reshape method for numpy (also below). However, I can't tell which arguments belong to which parameter.

Because this thing is supposed to load in picture data, I'm guessing 32,32 might be the image size, and would correspond to the `newshape` parameter?

I don't have a clue what 1000,3 are doing: the term "array_like" for the a parameter is confusing, and I don't know why 4 parameters are given if there's only 3 for the method, or how python would know that 32,32 is one argument, if it really is (why no `[]`?)

Basically, what parameter does each argument (passed in) belong to? And how on earth can it tell? And how did X go from being an object from the pickle load that has numpy methods on it? Is that even possible?

```
   datadict = pickle.load(f)
    X = datadict['data']
    Y = datadict['labels']
    X = X.reshape(10000, 3, 32, 32)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify: is that code snippet that you've included something you've written and are trying to debug, or some code you're trying to understand?

Comment: option b.. someone else's code

Comment: What data type is datadict['data']?  If is is a numpy array / matrix what is its size?  Just to confirm is the reshape line throwing an error?

Comment: @BenJ I don't know, hpaulj says it's an array, my brother just said it's a numpy.ndarray, and basically said somethings similar to hpaulj, "also there's reshape on the numpy package, but also a reshape method on the ndarray object itsself" , and "it just looks like you can pass in the shape like that.."

Answer (score 4):

The documentation you've linked is slightly different than what is actually happening, which may explain your confusion. The actual documentation, which is effectively the same function but set up as an object method instead of a library method, is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html).

In this case, the (10000, 3, 32, 32) corresponds to the shape of the output array. So your output is actually a 4-dimensional array with shape (10000, 3, 32, 32). I suspect that if this is supposed to be image data, you could have a 32x32 image with RGB values and 1,000 images.

Additionally, pickle stores type information when you store objects, so this is how it knows that the object is a numpy array!

Comment: Thanks! that agrees with, "[...] anyways it looks like its making a 10000 pic list of 32x32 pixel rbg images" I still want to know though, where on earth does it say anywhere that 3 stands for rgb?

Comment: It doesn't, but you said it is image data and the classical way to represent an image in computer science is as a 3-tensor (three-dimensional array) with pixel location utilizing two of the dimensions and the third is the red content, green content, and blue content of each pixel.

Comment: Well, I did not understand that, the prototype shows that `reshape()` receive a `shape` argument, so the correct call is `reshape((10000, 3, 32, 32))`, why `reshape(10000, 3, 32, 32)` also works?

Comment: I was struggling with this issue the whole day today. Your explanation helped me solve it! I was unable to figure out for a long time what does the first or the four parameters mean in reshape. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This loads a dictionary from the file:

```
datadict = pickle.load(f)
```

Then select two values from the dictionary.  Ordinary dictionary key indexing:

```
X = datadict['data']
Y = datadict['labels']
```

Evidently `X` is a `numpy` array. `reshape` is a method (a function that 'belongs' to the array).

```
X = X.reshape(10000, 3, 32, 32)
```

A `numpy` array has a property called `shape`.  After this `reshape`, `X.shape` should return `(10000, 3, 32, 32)`, the shape of a 4dimensional array.  The numbers are the `newshape` parameter described in the documentation.

The documentation is for the function version of `reshape`.  It would be used as:

```
X = np.reshape(X, (10000, 3, 32, 32))
```

Same functionality, just a different way of invoking it.

To go on from here you probably need to study `numpy` documentation.

---

The documentation for the method version is:

> a.reshape(shape, order='C')
>
> Returns an array containing the same data with a new shape.
>
> Refer to `numpy.reshape` for full documentation.